# OpenGL Making a Room in a given space and camera

Tags: c++, opengl

This is the setting I have to work with (I cannot change any of these values)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
const GLdouble FRUSTDIM = 100.0f;

void reshape(int w, int h) // Resize the GL Window. w=width, h=height
{
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glFrustum(-FRUSTDIM, FRUSTDIM, -FRUSTDIM, FRUSTDIM, 320., 640.);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}
```

I want to build a wall, but something is wrong and I dont quite understand. If I'm not mistaken, the current space is (-100 - 100)x(-100 - 100)x(320 - 640) and the camera is currently at 0,0,320

I want to make a room, but I can't even set up a wall :(....

I tried using QUADS and QUAD_STRIP, but it still wont show up when I run it D:

My code:

```
void display(void)
{
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3f(1,1,1);
    glVertex3f(50,50,420);
    glVertex3f(50,-50,420);
    glVertex3f(-50,-50,420);
    glVertex3f(-50,50,420);
    glEnd();

    glutSwapBuffers();
    glFlush();  
}
```

I just need to draw a wall to get myself going. If there is any code u think is required to solve my problem, comment and I will edit my question. (FYI other codes are working fine because the skeleton was give to me to start myself going).

Comment: Given the code you have right now, your camera is still at 0,0,0.  Add a glTransform to change your modelview matrix (move where the camera is).  Additionally, don't have your wall take up your whole frustum or you won't be able to tell where it is at first.  You're also setting your wall up at the very end of you far plane so you may not be able to see it there either. Put it between your near and Far (320 and 640).  Read about what glFrustum does, it will help you visualize what is happening.

Comment: @zero298 Even if I try different values for the vertices, I still can't find any change in the space when I run... I tried 'glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, 320)';, but it still doesnt work :(

Comment: Can you post the rest of your display() function then?  And are you using GLUT?

Comment: By default the OpenGL view goes down the *negative* Z axis, so the the visible Z range is -320 … -640.

Comment: @datenwolf I tried setting z to -420, but still no change :(

Comment: @LarsChung: You might want to look at https://github.com/datenwolf/codesamples/blob/master/samples/OpenGL/frustum/frustum.c to get an idea what glFrustum actually does. Compile and execute the program, play with the window sizes.

Comment: @datenwolf gets compilation error D:

Comment: @LarsChung: Which one exactly? There's a Makefile one level up that should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs to include this:

```
glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT|GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); // clearing window    
glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); 
glLoadIdentity();
```

to make the window clear for you to see the object. Additionally:

```
glTranslatef(-100,-100,-630.0);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
/* Back Wall */
glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glNormal3f(0,0,1);
glVertex3f(0,0,0);
glVertex3f(200,0,0);
glVertex3f(200,200,0);
glVertex3f(0,200,0);
glEnd();
```

this would make the wall (pretty much the same, but just added translate before building it).